# Firefox XPCOM component - Permission denied to call method UnnamedClass

Tags: firefox, xpcom, firefox-3

Can a firefox XPCOM component read and write page content across multiple pages?

Scenario:
A bunch of local HTML and javascript files. A "Main.html" file opens a window "pluginWindow", and creates a plugin using:

`netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');

var obj = Components.classes[cid].createInstance();

plugin = obj.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.IPlugin);

plugin.addObserver(handleEvent);`

The plugin that has 3 methods.

`IPlugin.Read` - Read data from plugin
`IPlugin.Write` - Write data to the plugin
`IPlugin.addObserver` - Add a callback handler for reading.

The "Main.html" then calls into the pluginWindow and tries to call the plugin method Write.

I receive an error:

`Permission denied to call method UnnamedClass.Write`

Comment: Are you sure you meant to tag this "c++"?  Perhaps "Javascript" would be a better fit...

As far as the actual question goes, sorry, I have no idea :(

Comment: I tagged as C++, because this is a C++ plugin, and hopefully answers would be geared toward c++ solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, is your C++ code really a [plugin](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins) or an [XPCOM component](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM), possibly installed as part of an [extension](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions)? Sounds like it's the later.

If so, it's not usable from untrusted JS code - any web page or a local HTML file. It's fully usable from privileged code, the most common type of which is the [extension](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions) code.

You're working around this problem when creating the component using the `enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect')` call. This is not really recommended, unless this will not be distributed to users (since this call pops a confusing box and if you set a preference to always allow file:// scripts use XPCOM, it may be a security problem, since not all local pages are trusted - think saved web pages).

Your `Write` call fails for the same reason - file:// pages are not trusted to use XPCOM components. You probably can get it to work if you add another `enablePrivilege` call in the same function as the Write call itself.

Depending on the situation, there may be a better solution.

If your files must be treated as trusted, you may want to package them as an extension and access them via a chrome:// URL. This gives the code in those pages permissions to call any XPCOM component, including yours.

If the component's methods are safe to use from any page or if the environment is controlled and no untrusted pages are loaded in the browser, you could make your component accessible to content (search for nsSidebar in [mozilla code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/) for an example and also for `nsISecurityCheckedComponent`).

Oh, and when you don't get good answers here, you should definitely try the mozilla newsgroups/mailing lists.

[edit in reply to a comment] Consider putting the code that needs to call the component in a chrome:// script. Alternatively, you should be able to "bless" your pages with the chrome privileges using code like [this](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/docshell/base/nsAboutRedirector.cpp#91) (note that it does the opposite of what you need - stripping away the chrome privileges).

Comment: You are correct. The c++ code is actually an XPCOM component. The pages are returned from a custom protocol, and yes, they are always safe. The component is only safe in the context of pages returned from the protocol handler.

Comment: (Replied in the answer body. Comments are limited to 300 chars...)

Answer (score 1):

Does Main.html and that other window run with chrome privileges?
If you access Main.html "normally", just putting it on the location bar of Firefox, then it will have restrictions to what it can do (Otherwise, an arbitrary web page could do exactly the same).

If you are creating a firefox plugin, place your code in a XUL overlay.

If you really want to allow any web page to do whatever it is your plugin does, you can establish some mechanism through wich the page can ask the plugin to do the operation with its chrome privileges and send the result to the page afterwards.

If you are NOT making a firefox extension...then I am afraid I misunderstood something, could you explain it more?

Comment: Does main.html run with chrome priviledges: no.

I am not sure what you mean about place my code in an XUL overlay. The code is native C++.

The compiled dll is placed in the firefox/components directory and is loaded when the javascript in main.html creates it.

Researching XUL overlay now. Thanks!